# Pass parameters across sklearn pipelines

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am writing a custom sklearn pipeline as follows:

Step 1:

```py
class Step1(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, input1: str = "Input1") -> None:
        self.input1 = input1

    def fit(self, X: pd.DataFrame, y: pd.DataFrame = None):
        self.some_param = X["my_col"].mean()
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        return X
```

Step 2:

```py
class Step2(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, input2: str = "Input2") -> None:
        self.input2 = input2

    def fit(self, X: pd.DataFrame, y: pd.DataFrame = None):
        return self
    
    def transform(self, X):
        ######### I want to use the variable: 'some_param' here
        X["my_other_col"] = X["my_other_col"] - (some_param)
        return X
```

The pipeline is:

```py
pipeline = Pipeline([
('step1', Step1()),
('step2', Step2())
])
```

In Step1, there is a parameter: 'some_param' that is fitted/defined somehow and that I want to use in Step2. Is there any way I can do that?

I tried set_param but the behaviour was not as expected

Answer (score 2):

**Brainstorming Idea:** If these parameters are not random variables (not changed/updated in each run), parameters can be retrieved by fitting step 1 before the pipeline runs. Please update `step2.transform(x)` function by adding `self.some_param`. Before running the pipeline, get the parameters from step 1.

```
class Step2(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    ...
    def transform(self, X):
        if hasattr(self, 'some_param'):
            X["my_other_col"] = X["my_other_col"] - self.some_param
        return X
```

Manually fit and get some_param:

```
step1 = Step1()
step2 = Step2()
step1.fit(df)       # manually fit step1 and pass some_param to step2
step2.some_param = step1.some_param

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('step1', step1),
    ('step2', step2)
])
```

**Another way:**

Defining a new step (setsomeparam):

```
class SetSomeParam(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, base_estimator):
        self.base_estimator = base_estimator

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        if hasattr(self.base_estimator, 'some_param'):
            self.base_estimator.some_param = self.base_estimator.some_param
        return X

class Step2(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    ...
    def transform(self, X):
        if hasattr(self, 'some_param'):
            X["my_other_col"] = X["my_other_col"] - self.some_param
        return X
```

New pipeline:

```
step1 = Step1()
set_param = SetSomeParam(step1)
step2 = Step2()

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('step1', step1),
    ('set_param', set_param),
    ('step2', step2)
])

result = pipeline.fit_transform(df)
```